# Unable to Debug Library Projects with ADT v14 - Source Not Found

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-library

Ever since upgrading my current projects to use the new R14 Tools in Eclipse, I'm now unable to debug any code that exists in my library projects.

When I hit a break point in my library project code, instead of Eclipse opening the original source file, it opens up the read-only copy of the source file contained within the JAR with the message "Source not found".

I've searched around for a solution to this, but have yet to come across anything.  Does anybody else have any suggestions?  It's quite a pain not being able to debug.

**EDIT**

The issue has came back and I'm no longer able to debug.  I haven't changed any project settings around or anything.  Very frustrating.

Comment: I have the same issue!  Someone find the fix as I have an itchy upvote finger!

Comment: Same problem!! None of the solutions work for me either.

I can no longer debug library files because of this (cannot add or remove breakpoints from a class file)

Comment: Has anyone found a working solution to this? The accepted answer does now work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After having this issue as well and doing a little research, I came across this thread and another one that tipped me off. I was pulling my hair out already.

It turns out that the problem is with the build order of your projects (mine was anyway). Since ADT/SDK v14 changed the way library projects are referenced, the build order needs to be correct. Make sure all of the libraries your app uses are built first. I just moved the "src" and "gen" folders for each of my projects to the bottom and now it builds the library first and I am able to debug it and view the source of my library files through the main project.

In case someone doesn't know where to do this, in Eclipse, right click on your project and "Build Path" and then click "Configure Build Path". Then, on the "Order and Export" tab, move the two folders for your project to the bottom of the list below your libraries. I did this for all of my projects and the library projects.

You can also do it globally in Eclipse from Windows->Preferences->General->Workspace->Build Order and moving your library projects to the top. I think the build order defined in each project will override this though, so you may want to do it in both places to solve the issue now and for future projects.

Comment: Well, after moving the "src" and "gen" folders down to the bottom of the build order, debugging was still not possible.  After this, I had removed the library project reference from the section in the "Android" tab where you add the library projects.  After adding the library project back, I am now able to debug.  I'm not sure what combination of things solved it, but I believe changing the build order helped.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad I could help. Good info on removing and re-adding the library to the project too. I like this way that they reference the libraries better, but Google probably should have been able to clean it up a little better to avoid all these little issues when everyone updated.

Comment: Just as an update, the issue is back, so I can't really say that I found a solution.

Comment: @hooked82 Your suggestion of removing the library and adding it back also helped me. Thank you hooked82 and ssuperz28!

Comment: @hooked82 You'll have to remove and re-add the library every time you clean/rebuild, or the problem returns. eh.

Comment: What a PITA, thanks RyanM.  Does anybody know if there's a known issue for this over at google?  This seems like 2 steps backwards.

Comment: @hooked82, see Kuffs answer for a filed bug. The link also has a workaround that works well for me.

Comment: This helps but only if src folder stays above the gen folder.

Answer (score 44):

Tried all of the above and it did not work for me, however the workaround detailed here did.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20731

> 1. Start debugging, and run until you hit a breakpoint (and precisely get a .class file instead of the .java you would like to have)
> 2. Right click in the Debug view of the Debug perspective (for example on the call stack), and choose "Edit Source Lookup Path"
> 3. Add all your projects above "Default", via "Add..." > "Java project" > "Select All"

(I'm using ADT 15.0.2 preview from http://tools.android.com/download)

Comment: Comment 2 from the link above worked beautifully for me.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20731#c2

Comment: Another note, this worked exactly for me, I simply selected my current testing project and the library project and moved it above the default.  +1 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in a project today. The project consists of an app which has two library dependencies. I could not see code during debugging and when using auto-completion when overriding methods Eclipse was unable to deduce proper argument names.

First of all, the problem manifested itself by showing the the 'gen' folder was used as the one that contained the source. To check whether this is the same issue go to your app project, open the Android dependencies and have a look at the properties of the your library dependencies. Location path said /libraryprojectname/gen.

If this is also your problem then go to the 'Order and Export' tab of each library project and move the 'gen' item below the 'src' item. As soon as you click OK Eclipse will work a bit and when you check the Android dependency properties the location path should say: /libraryprojectname/src. Open click the dependency and open any class inside the jar. It should show the source.

I am using ADT plugin 20.0.3 with Android SDK Tools 20.0.3 and Android SDK Platform Tools 14.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me on Eclipse Juno:

In Project Properties/Java Build Path:

- In the Projects tab, added my library projects.
- In the Order and Export tab, moved my library projects to the top, and checked them

Not sure if it's relevant, but Android SDK tools is rev 20.0.3 and Android SDK platform tools is 14.

Comment: This order worked for me: (from the top) Android Dependencies, Android Private Libraries, SRC, GEN

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are opeining library project and there you put brakepoint.
Try this: On main project open Library Projects->[yourlibrary.jar]->[yourfile.class] from Package Explorer, and then in .class file put brakepoints.
This works for me at least :)

Comment: I haven't tried this approach, but I don't see it as an acceptable solution to being able to properly debug an application.  Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens to me. Not sure about the reason but the way I solve is:

Remove the main project from eclipse. -- Closs Eclipse -- Delete the jar file in the library project -- Open Eclipse -- Wait for the library project to compile -- Import the main project

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs with release 21 of ADT inside Juno. As a workaround, in the "debug" view of the debug perspective (where you see threads and method invocation traces), right click and edit source lookup path.