# Unable to debug library project

Tags: android

I just upgraded to the latest Android SDK tools. Now when I set a break point in a library project and the breakpoint is hit I just get a blank .class file and can no longer debug or step the source code. What do I need to do to fix the latest SDK tools to add back support for debugging library projects?

At this point there appears to be no way to debug a library project at all?

.classpath file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

None of the items in this class path seem to correspond to the library project that I am including. This is the class path of the main project, not the library project.

Does anyone know of any new documentation for how to do library projects that came out since the latest tools release? The existing documentation seems to no longer be valid. I used to be able to step and debug any library that was included into a top level Android App. So to fully test a library I could do it through the delivery main app. But now it seems that can no longer be done.

Do I need to set the library to not be a library, then debug and test the library stand alone, then set the library back to being a library right before I deliver? This seems like the SDK has been crippled since the last release.

Comment: Possible duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899183/unable-to-debug-library-projects-with-adt-v14-source-not-found)

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate of this. I have already read this question. It does not solve this problem. Also the accepted answer does not work as is indicated by the comment in the question "The issue has came back and I'm no longer able to debug. I haven't changed any project settings around or anything. Very frustrating." In the future please don't just do a search and reply duplicate when it is obvious that the link does not help. I am tired of questions being marked as duplicate that are not, or have no known good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, but I had to redo my project setup once I updated to the newest Android SDK tools.  I basically removed the library project and re-added it:

- Right click project > Properties > Android > remove libraries here.
- Right click project > Properties > Java Build Path > remove libraries
  from Source tab.
- Right click project > Properties > Android > re-add
  libraries here.

*** If you have any libraries with libraries in them then you need to perform these steps on those included libraries as well. You essentially need to do this once for every library in your project when you are upgrading to the new tools.

You should see your libraries' source files within your project in the Navigator tab.  I click on the library source from here and set the breakpoint.  I run in debug and the breakpoint works fine.

Not sure what will happen click the library source from outside your project's context.  Good luck!

**edit:**

`.classpath`:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried your steps with no luck. From the Navigator view there is no library source. From the Package View under Library Projects I can see the .jar file and browse the .class files but not the source. When I click on the .class it says source not found. Do I need to do something to get the source to show up in the Navigator tab as you say?

Comment: Hm can you post your `.classpath` file of your project?  I noticed mine got changed when I updated the SDK.

Comment: In the new SDK, they moved all the library paths to project.properties, so I think this is okay for the main project's .classpath.  I noticed in one of my projects where the debugging and jumping to library code does not work, it had `<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>` in the library's .classpath.  I changed the library's .classpath to remove `exported="true"`, restarted eclipse and it worked... so weird.

Comment: So are you stumped with this too?

Comment: When I removed `exported="true"` form my library's `.classpath`, I am able to debug, but the library source files do not show up under my main project.  So it did work okay, but not sure why it's different than my other projects.

Comment: Ahhh got it working. One of my libraries had a library inside of it, i.e. it referenced another library. I had to perform your steps on that library as well and that fixed it. I updated your answer with a note about libraries with libraries, if you want to approve the edit I can accept the response. Again thanks for the help.